# Image getting corrupt in the gmail

Tags: php, gmail, opencart

I'm working on an opencart project. There i'm sending an email which contains images and some links and when i send it to gmail the contained images getting corrupt. but it works on other email services like yahoo,zoho.

Exact image url :
http://localhost/projectname/image/cache/catalog/xx-3d-image-name-400x400.png

After send it to gamil:
https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/z6YidwAumXA-argnKG9tdSJ0yPYJiUeERmhTSOZ8JU1H-wtrEa2Bhm10mHhyEW_eZI1IaODyhoM04kTpIIYjozp14uxJE0I_z9TK4b_Y=s0-d-e1-ft#http://server.name/image/cache/catalog/Black

therefore anyone can give me a solution for this issue?

Comment: Yes please use a **real url** instead of localhost to host images... :)

Comment: Remember `localhost` to you is your server So `localhost` to google is their server. Your images dont exists on googles server

Comment: Thank you all got it now. i confused with, why images are appearing in other email services like yahoo,zoho  from localhost images. now i understand the problem. thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google uses a sort of proxy for loading e-mail images so they can cache them. Because you are hosting your application from localhost, the Google proxy cannot reach your image and a broken image is shown in your email.

The reason this works with Yahoo and Zoho is that they link to the image directly and you are probably running the application on the same machine. If you would open these emails on another machine, the links would also be broken.

The solution for this is hosting your images on a server that can be reached by anyone using a domain name.

Comment: thank you for your answer. now i  understood the situation.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this fixed your problem, please mark this as the solution so others might also find this.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation brother. That's why i couldn't give you a  plus mark